# How to find duplicate rows in database table and update flag to the duplicate rows in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Description: Let's say there are 5 rows in a table. 3 rows are duplicate, so i need to update 2 of 3 rows as 'Y' since they are duplicate and write the 2 rows to a .csv file. How to do that? below is some of my codes.

```
  public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Account, 
   Account>chunk(100).reader(reader(dataSource)).processor(processor())
            .writer(writer()).build();
}

@Bean
public Job writeDuplicateJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("writeDuplicateJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end()
            .build();
}
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Account> reader(DataSource dataSource) {

 final String QUERY="SELECT CUSTOMERID,SAVINGSNUMBER,CURRENTNUMBER,CREDITNUMBER,LOAN_ID,DUPLICATE FROM ACCOUNT";
    
     return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Account>().name("QUERY").sql(QUERY)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Account.class))
            .build();
}


     @Bean
     public FlatFileItemWriter<Account> writer(){
    FlatFileItemWriter<Account> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<Account>();
    writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("accounts.csv"));
    
    DelimitedLineAggregator<Account> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<Account>();
    lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Account>  fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Account>();
    fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"customerId","savingsNumber","currentNumber","creditNumber","loanId","duplicate"});
    lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
    
    writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
    return writer;
}

 //item writer
@Override
public List<Account> process(List<Account> item) throws Exception {
    for (Account acc : item) {
        if (seenAccounts.contains(acc)) {
            acc.setDuplicate("Y");
            finalList.add(acc);
        } else
            acc.setDuplicate("N");

        finalList.add(acc);
    }

    return finalList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find duplicates, you can use a SQL query like the following:

```
select id, field, count(*) from table group by field having count(*) > 1
```

Now you could find non duplicates with a query like

```
select * from table where id not in (
   select id, field, count(*) from table group by field having count(*) > 1
)
```

and write them to a file, but since you need to flag duplicates with `Y`, I'm not sure you can do that in one step. You need to proceed with two steps:

- Step 1: find duplicates with the aforementioned query and update the duplicate flag to `Y`
- Step 2: read non duplicate items and write them to a file